# Space character not being matched by regex in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pcre

I want to block any request that contains an ID that contains any non-numeric character using mod_rewite, or an empty ID. I have the following rule in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ID=(\d*[^\d&]+\d*)*(&|$)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Which is working except for requests that contain a space character eg.

```
GET /page.php?ID=5 5 HTTP/1.1
```

The space character between the two 5s is successfully matched by `[^\d&]+` when I use various test suites (such as https://regex101.com/) but this type of request is still getting through.

What do I need to change?

(yes, incorrect user input is handled in my PHP so it doesn't matter if this gets through)

Comment: spaces are encoded in urls using `%20` why are you worries about that?

Comment: I believe you may just use `ID=[0-9]*[^0-9&]` regex. No need to capture anything if you do not use `%1` / `%2`.

Comment: @Andreykul spaces are encoded for requests from regular browsers yes, but these are requests probing for vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I also want to block an empty ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Andreykul spaces are encoded for requests from regular browsers yes, but these are requests probing for vulnerabilities.

Possibly vulnerabilities in the webserver itself, rather than your web application... (?)

> ```
> GET /page.php?ID=5 5 HTTP/1.1
> ```

The "problem" with this is that it's an invalid/malformed request. For this to be valid, it *must* be URL encoded. The (literal) *space* is a special character in the first line of the request and acts as a delimiter between the "Method", "Request-URI" and "HTTP-Version" parts of the header.

Since the request is *invalid*, it would be reasonable to expect it to already be blocked at the server level with a `400 Bad Request`.

If the server is not blocking the request then you are likely to experience unexpected behaviour. Which is possibly what you are seeing here...

For such a request, if you examine the `QUERY_STRING` server variable you will see that it doesn't contain the space or the second `5`. The value is truncated *before* the literal space, it simply contains `ID=5`. (Consequently, this is also what PHP sees.) So, your regex (*CondPattern*) never matches.

However, the complete request URI is present in the first line of the request (as you posted above) - this is available in the `THE_REQUEST` Apache server variable. It will probably be preferable to simply block any request that contains literal spaces (which is *invalid* anyway), rather than searching specifically for requests containing the `ID` parameter. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s.*\s.*\s
RewriteRule ^ - [R=400]
```

This checks for any whitespace contained between the outer space delimiters.

Reference:
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html

Comment: This is a great answer thank you, well done for seeing through to the root of the problem.

Comment: Nice solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)ID=\d+(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

And if you only want it to affect requests that do have an ID parameter in the query string (so requests with no ID are allowed):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(?:\%(?:20|09))*ID(?:\%(?:20|09))*= [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)ID=\d+(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

I also added `[NC]` (non-case-sensitive) so that `iD` etc. will also be covered by this.

Comment: What's the reason for the `\s*` around the parameter name in the _CondPattern_? I wouldn't necessarily include the `NC` flag on the _negated_ condition. In PHP the URL param name is case-sensitive, so `iD` etc. is probably better blocked. (?)

Comment: The `\s*` is there to make sure all attempts to specify an ID are caught, which is the OP's main concern. Seems worth doing? Good point about `NC` on the negated conditions, have removed those.

Comment: But could `\s*` ever match anything? The `QUERY_STRING` server variable is URL encoded so it should never contain a literal whitespace character in a valid request - and any malformed request should be blocked by the server? `\s*` just seems superfluous to me, but maybe I'm missing something? Just curious. (+1)

Comment: I was working on the theory that the URL was decoded before being matched against, but just tested and indeed not. Agree with you and have removed that.

Comment: @user82217 I added a match on URL-encoded space or horizontal tab in place of the previous `\s`, although really need to test to see if Apache would allow that through and whether PHP would ignore the space.

Comment: @SuperDuperApps thank you for this answer, but my ISP is genuinely allowing requests with a literal space through so it turns out this is not really a regex issue. Sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: My answer covers that, since if the ID parameter contains anything other than numbers, it is rejected. That includes spaces. You asked specifically for blocking invalid ID parameters, which is exactly what this does.